# Battery wasting via voltage regulator

Tags: power-electronics

I made a circuit for a tape (or block) LED that will turn on with 12V.

I had two 9V batteries, so to convert them to 12V supply that is suitable for LED I used two linear 8V and 5V regulators - connecting them together  gave me an almost 13V supply.

That worked but what happened is that after a few days the batteries wasted and drops to 0V and 2V. (The lights were off and that happened.)

What's the problem in my circuit? Are the linear regulators wasting power?

[image]

Comment: Yes, linear regulators waste a lot of power. They effectively burn off the extra as heat. You are also missing a current limiting resistor for the LED.

Comment: you also used crappy batteries ... a standard 9 V battery contains six AAAA cells in series ... think about the amount of current that a AAAA cell can provide ..... why don't you simply use 8 AA cells in series to get 12 V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7800 series of regulators take a quiescent current of a few milliamps.  This is probably what's burning down your 9V batteries when you're not operating the unit.  Modern LDOs can be had with quiescent currents in the microamp range.

When operating, your efficiency is under 70%--not bad for really low duty cycle, but if your on time is significant you might consider a switching supply.  Second choice would be to put the batteries in series and use a single LDO with low Iq to regulate from 18 to 13V.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linear Regulator configuration is not optimal, and as @Cristobol already mentioned, their quiescent current is draining your battery. The quiescent current problem could be improved if you physically disconnect the batteries if the circuit is not in operation as shown in the following picture:
[image]

If you are comfortable with DCDC converters, you could also use a boost converter, e.g.  [LM2733](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2733.pdf) and connect both batteries in parallel as follows:

[image: Circuit]

A typical arrangement for the boost converter is shown in the following picture (feedback resistors must be accordingly defined to obtain 13V):

[image: Boost converter]

Comment: The 7805 is by no means a "low drop out" (LDO) regulator.  It is a linear regulator.  LDO regulators are a subclass of linear regulators.

Comment: @JRE you are right. It erroneous typed LDO. Thank you.